# Textview overlapping button when opening keypad?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

When I open keypad my textview overlap with button. Below "author info" is overlapping button when I open keypad. Can anyone tell me what's went wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/actionbar"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="13dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_input"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_btn_join"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_join"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- author info -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/author_name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/author_url"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.I don't want that my textview overlap button. It should remain on it place even after I open my keypad.

Comment: Atach your manifest file

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Comment: Please tell us why how does this help solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your activity on manifest set windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", so the activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. For more check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: I did that but that even didn't worked. What worked for me is very simple. I simple changed Relative Layout to Linear Layout and everything working perfect now. By the way thanks for the answer.